# Want level curve in the xy-plane, but the plot is 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to make a figure to visualize Lagranges multiplier method. This means I want to draw the graph of some function z = f(x,y), but also the constraint g(x,y) = c. Because I want to draw the graph of f, this must obviously be a 3D plot. But the constraint g(x,y) = c is a level curve of g, and should lie in the xy-plane.

I am using Python, and here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
X = np.arange(-5,5,0.5)
Y = X
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = 50 - X**2 - Y**2
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_zlim(0, 50)

g = X**2+Y**2
CS = ax.contour(X,Y,g)

plt.show()
```

and this is the output:
[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuMzD.png)

I only need one level curve of g in the xy-plane. Now, I have several, and none of them lies at z = 0. Ideally, I should also somehow mark out the points of z=f(x,y) that lies directly over g(x,y) = c.
I would really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Seems that the z's of your level curves are flipped.

Comment: The level curves are for g.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the optional argument "offset", so that the contour gets projected to a plane. To be in z=0:

```
CS = ax.contour(X,Y,g, offset = 0)
```

See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.contourf).

Comment: Thank you! I changed the command to plt.contour(X, Y, g, offset = 0), and now they are all in the xy-plane.

Comment: The final thing I need to do is to mark out the points on z = f(x,y) that lies directly above this level curve. I thought about somehow managing to collect the points on the level curve in a list, and then again plot z = f(x,y) with these points as the argument. But maybe Python already has a command for doing this?